# Nested objects in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a small ember set loads products and display them. So every product has store know I wanna link from a product page to the store, but I have no idea where I have to tell ember that products have stores

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
  @route 'products'
  @route 'product', path: '/product/:product_id'
  @route 'store', path: '/store/:store_id'

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller)->
    $.get('api', (response) ->
      products = response.response.products //this object holds the store
        .filter((p)->  p.gender == 'male')
        .map ((p)-> App.Product.create(p))

      controller.set('content', products)
    )
    controller.set 'name', 'Produkte'


App.Product = Ember.Object.extend
  style: (->
    "background-image:url('" + @get("image") + "')"
  ).property("url")
```

the template

```
script(type="text/x-handlebars", data-template-name="product")
    <h1>{{page_title}}</h1>
    <img {{bindAttr src="image"}}>
    {{#linkTo "store" store}}Store{{/linkTo}}
```

the products json

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'product1',
    gender: 'male'
    store: {id: 1, name: 'store1'}
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "tell ember products have stores" and share an example of what your api is returning?

Comment: My goal is that in the template which renders a `App.Product` object it will know that there is a store object in product with an id so it can build the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems one of the ember WTF moments. The `store` variable seems to be some kind of an reserved word. When I set the key to `_store` it works as expected:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
  @route 'products'
  @route 'product', path: '/product/:product_id'
  @route 'store', path: '/store/:store_id'

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller)->
    $.get('api', (response) ->
      products = response.response.products
        .filter((p)->  p.gender == 'male')
        .map ((p)->
          p._store = p.store
          App.Product.create(p))

      controller.set('content', products)
    )
    controller.set 'name', 'Produkte'

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    console.log(model);

App.Product = Ember.Object.extend
  style: (->
    "background-image:url('" + @get("image") + "')"
  ).property("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you have **should work**

I've made a simple JSBIN that simulates your api and has a working [store link](http://jsbin.com/odobat/1/edit)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("store", {path: 'store/:store_id'});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return [{ id: 1, name: 'product1', gender: 'male', store: {id: 1, name: 'store1'}}];
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars">{{outlet}}</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h2>All Products:</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{name}} - {{#linkTo "store" store}}Store{{/linkTo}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="store">
  <h1>Store: {{name}}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Strange, all I got in my example is `Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.` Could the `App.Product` created by myself be the problem?